# PostgreSQL COPY Syntax Failure (My issue - PostgreSQL is fine)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy, postgresql-15

I'm sure it is obvious that I am a "NEWB" - gotta start somewhere, right?  Having an issue understanding how to implement PostgreSQL COPY as depicted in the image below:  [PostgreSQL COPY Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W9QJ.png)

Here's the query I attempted to run:

```
COPY SqlProject.CovidVaccinations
FROM '/Users/brucebeck/Desktop/RDBMS_Work/ATA_PortfolioProject1/CovidVaccinations.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Query result was "ERROR: schema "sqlproject" does not exist SQL state: 3F000 (Which according to PostgreSQL documentation means basically the same thing.  I'm guessing that my COPY statement is missing something PostgreSQL needs.

FWIW, I WAS able to load data into the target table (CovidVaccinations) in the SqlProject schema using pgAdmin 4's Import Data tool.  Trouble is, I did not learn exactly how to use the COPY command.

Any guidance the collective could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Advice: Never use UPPER case in your object names. Never. And if you do, always use double quotes around the object names, like "SqlProject"."CovidVaccinations"

Comment: Read [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Thanks Adrian.  Feedback greatly appreciated.